# General Question Relating to Efficiency of Amazon Lightsail RDS Queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-lightsail

I'm simply querying the number of rows (~2 Million) in a table using PostgreSQL. When I run this query on my local database it completes in under 1 second, However when I run the query on my remote Amazon Lightsail database it takes around 20 seconds to complete (The CPU utilization is below 10%). Indexing the table doesn't improve performance. Here is the query:

`select count(1) from photon_private.student_enrolment;`

When I run `EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers)` on the query I get the following:

[image]

When I run `VACUUM(FULL, ANALYZE, VERBOSE) photon_private.student_enrolment;` I get the following:

[image]

The container service running on Amazon has the following specs:
4 GB RAM,
2 virtual CPUs (vCPUs),
40 GB SSD Disk,
2 TB Transfer

It seems strange to me that the query should complete so fast locally, but take so long on Amazon. Could anybody tell me potential reasons for the difference and how I can improve performance on Amazon?

Comment: 1. Compare settings of database at your pc and Amazon server.
2. Use SSD disks.
3. Change your query to `select count(1) from data_table where expired is null`.

Comment: I suggest you need [AWS console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/?nc2=h_m_mc)

Comment: If you use SSD, you have only one way to figure out your problem. It's read PostgreSQL log file [get log from aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.PostgreSQL.html) and you can use profile to get information from AWS PostgreSQL server [plprofiler](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/profile-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-or-amazon-aurora-postgresql-pl-pgsql-code-using-plprofiler/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your execution plan shows that all the time is spent doing disk I/O. The I/O rate is about 45MB per second, which is rather slow. Since this is a hosted database, you'd have to pay for more disk bandwidth to speed this query up.

Calculating the row count of a table may be a simple query, but [it is definitely *not* cheap](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-count-made-fast/). So your best strategy is not to execute that query too often.

Comment: The disk is SSD based, also the table is the same size on my local machine and on Amazon so I don't think the size is the problem.

Comment: The SSD disk is probably throttled. We can only guess, unless you activate `track_io_timing` and run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` on your query. Edit the question and put the information there.

Comment: Then everything is clear, see my edited answer.

Comment: How were you able to calculate the I/O rate as 45MB/second ?

Comment: I/O timing divided by number of buffers read. A buffer is 8kB in size.